# How to prevent child from calling friends?

Tags: phone-app, parental-control

Even when the phone is locked to the maximum extent (bedtime on Google Family Link / Huawei parental controls), children are able to call friends. This is not what I want, especially during nights.

I have spent a lot of time on looking for a solution. This seems like something easy to implement (even locking the whole dialer app), however it looks like one would have to root the device to achieve this.

I found one trail, MMGuardian, that claims to allow contacts white list, but this is paid software and I'm looking for a free solution.

There is a [Google topic](https://support.google.com/android/thread/98771081/google-family-link-access-to-full-dialer-contacts?hl=en&fbclid=IwAR0FzLVgwxBC44aSsWw9yP50HvcTzshY9z74eKdrFl4Xk1chQ5Y69bROyiU) about this, on which a lot of people voted.

How come such a seemingly obvious functionality is not available?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this (due to a lack of that setting on my daughter's card), but it seems one can achieve it by setting [FDN (fixed dialing number)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_Dialing_Number?fbclid=IwAR2sm5PnluX400paF-7SeIcfOz6NohxuI1834QGaD28s7IWZUiNJXDxjh6o) - a SIM setting, though changing it doesn't seem very easy comparing to other parental controls.

> Fixed Dialing Number (FDN) is a service mode of a GSM mobile phone's SIM card. Numbers are added to the FDN list, and when activated, FDN restricts outgoing calls to only those numbers listed, or to numbers with certain prefixes. A notable exception is that emergency calls to 000, 112, 911, 999 and the like are exempt. Incoming calls are not blocked by FDN.
>
> One practical application of FDN is for parents to restrict the phone numbers their children can dial. The SIM card's PIN2 must be entered beforehand or when applying such settings.